# Error in multiple uploads

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem making multiple uploads of images in CodeIgniter 3. I tried the `MY_Upload Class`, and I tried other code, but none work for me.

Controller

```
function do_uploadMultiple(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/page/img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $nameField = 'imagem';
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($nameField)){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }else{
            $foto = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            return $foto['upload_data']['file_name'];

        }
    }

    public function cadastrarPage(){

        $data['nome_menu'] = $this->input->post('nome');
        $data['titulo'] = $this->input->post('titulo');
        $data['text'] = $this->input->post('text');
        $data['video'] = $this->input->post('video');
        $teste['imagem'] = $this->input->post('imagem');

        $id_abrase = $this->Abrase_model->cadastrarPage($data);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['imagem']['name']); $i++){
            $img['id_abrase'] = $id_abrase;
            $img['imagem'] = $this->do_uploadMultiple();

            $result = $this->Abrase_model->gravarImagem($img);
            if($result){
                echo 'yeah';
            }else{
                echo 'fail';
            }
        }


    }
```

View

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/abrase/cadastrarPage'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Nome da página no menu</label>
                    <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="titulo">Título</label>
                    <input id="titulo" name="titulo" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="text">Texto da Página</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="imagem">Selecione as imagens </label>
                    <input class="file" name="imagem[]" id="imagem" type="file" multiple data-show-upload="false">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="video">Vídeo</label>
                    <input type="text" name="video" id="video" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pdf">Arquivos</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Model

```
public function cadastrarPage($data){
        $this->db->set('data_add', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->set('excluido', 0);

        $this->db->insert('abrase', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

public function gravarImagem($data){
        return $this->db->insert('abrase_img', $data);
    }
```

And now the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 412

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tattica\ABRASE\application\controllers\Abrase.php
Line: 32
Function: do_upload

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tattica\ABRASE\application\controllers\Abrase.php
Line: 54
Function: do_uploadMultiple

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tattica\ABRASE\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I tried everything that I found in the web, but can't do it. I need help please.

Comment: You might want to show the do_upload/is_uploaded_file function since that is where the error is coming from and it's obviously because whatever is being passed to is_uploaded_file is an array and not a string as the error says.

Comment: The error message is very clear... start there.

Comment: I should do the role upload Multiple then inside the for, so you can spend one image at a time?

Comment: Codeigniter upload library is mainly for single uploads at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Codeigniter really cannot handle multiple file uploads, The multiple upload class was for an older codeigniter, But here is a code that you can use, This uses native PHP code and as far as I know, this is the only way to upload multiple in codeigniter.

```
  foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $index => $f)
  {
  $target_dir =  './assets';
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$index]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $files_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$index];
  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file))
  {
      //Filexists
      $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check file size
  if ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$index] > 5000000) 
  {
      echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) 
  {
      echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
      // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } 
  else 
  {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$index], $target_file)) 
      {
            //success
      }
      else
      {
          echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will test in the weekend, because I have other projects in deadline